# Error using "cdc_start_position" argument in the creating aws_dms_replication_task resource- terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, database-migration, aws-dms, terraform-aws-modules

I am using Terraform v1.1.0 on Mac 64bit and aws terraform provider 3.7.0 to build AWS DMS components.

Here is the block to create DMS replication task -

```
resource "aws_dms_replication_task" "dms_repl_task_rev" {
  cdc_start_position        = "4AF/B00000D0"
  migration_type            = var.dms_migration_type
  replication_instance_arn  = aws_dms_replication_instance.dms_repl_instance.replication_instance_arn
  replication_task_id       = "dms-replication-task-id-rev"
  replication_task_settings = "..."
  source_endpoint_arn       = aws_dms_endpoint.pg_dms_source_ep.endpoint_arn
  table_mappings            = "..."

  tags = {
    Name = "dms-test"
  }

  target_endpoint_arn = aws_dms_endpoint.s3_dms_target_ep.endpoint_arn
}
```

cdc_start_position is a valid arg as per documentation `https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/dms_replication_task`

However, I run into this error -

> ╷
> │ Error: Unsupported argument
> │
> │   on main.tf line 176, in resource "aws_dms_replication_task" "dms_repl_task_rev":
> │  176:   cdc_start_position        = "4AF/B00000D0"
> │
> │ An argument named "cdc_start_position" is not expected here.
> ╵

Has anyone used the parameter before. I believe my version should be supporting the parameters here.

Thank you.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cdc_start_position` was added in [v3.62.0](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/releases?q=cdc_start_position&expanded=true) of aws provider. Thus it seems you have older version and **must upgrade**.

Comment: AWS provider is 3.7.0. I am using later version than the above. Terraform v1.1.1
on darwin_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.7.0

Comment: I had to upgrade terraform from 1.1.0(previous version) that gave above bug to 1.1.1(latest tf version). That fixed the issue. Thanks for checking in.